# How do I load a dictionary data into JSON?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

This is probably very simple. I'm playing with webhooks and one of my tests throws a JSON dict data that I'm trying to copy/paste to my terminal and pprint it. However I'm getting errors. Why? Please help.

```
json.loads({"signature": {"timestamp": "1542320326", "token": "78b89c864547e371f7d708fcde9ccf3df937ce0e296cff8683", "signature": "822ae5f14a85dc25dacfd53a7ab1d55f03529aae0e8535d29758740924fde385"}, "event-data": {"tags": ["my_tag_1", "my_tag_2"], "timestamp": 1521233123.501324, "envelope": {"sending-ip": "173.193.210.33"}, "log-level": "warn", "id": "-Agny091SquKnsrW2NEKUA", "campaigns": [], "user-variables": {"my_var_1": "Mailgun Variable #1", "my-var-2": "awesome"}, "flags": {"is-test-mode": false}, "message": {"headers": {"to": "Alice <alice@example.com>", "message-id": "20110215055645.25246.63817@biennial-dot-filings.us", "from": "Bob <bob@biennial-dot-filings.us>", "subject": "Test complained webhook"}, "attachments": [], "size": 111}, "recipient": "alice@example.com", "event": "complained"}})
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'false' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

In Python, `false` is not a valid type / expression. I think what you want is `False`. You can read more [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/boolean).

As @Uku mentioned, you can use `json.loads()` to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

Json does not map directly to Python data structures.

you have to do `json.loads("your string"`) instead. In JSON it's `false`, where's in Python we have `False`

for example

```
json.loads('{"signature": {"timestamp": "1542320326", "token": "78b89c864547e371f7d708fcde9ccf3df937ce0e296cff8683", "signature": "822ae5f14a85dc25dacfd53a7ab1d55f03529aae0e8535d29758740924fde385"}, "event-data": {"tags": ["my_tag_1", "my_tag_2"], "timestamp": 1521233123.501324, "envelope": {"sending-ip": "173.193.210.33"}, "log-level": "warn", "id": "-Agny091SquKnsrW2NEKUA", "campaigns": [], "user-variables": {"my_var_1": "Mailgun Variable #1", "my-var-2": "awesome"}, "flags": {"is-test-mode": false}, "message": {"headers": {"to": "Alice <alice@example.com>", "message-id": "20110215055645.25246.63817@biennial-dot-filings.us", "from": "Bob <bob@biennial-dot-filings.us>", "subject": "Test complained webhook"}, "attachments": [], "size": 111}, "recipient": "alice@example.com", "event": "complained"}}')
```

Answer (score 0):

`json.loads` expects a string as its argument. In order to make the JSON object you copied into a valid string literal in Python, you need to surround it with quotes.

Since the JSON string itself contains the `"` character, you have to use `'`:

```
json.loads('{"signature": {"timestamp": "1542320326", ... }}')
```